# Can SignalR be used with asp.net WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, signalr, real-time-updates

I want to use `SignalR` in my project for real time updates.

My project is developed in `WebForms`.

I searched for for 3,4 days but all I found were MVC examples. 
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use SignalR with webforms. See below for an example from the tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526876/AddingplusSignalRplustoplusanplusASP-NetplusWebFor)

1. Create a new ASP.NET WebForms project targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or later
2. Change the home page to contain the following

   ```
   <asp:content runat="server" id="BodyContent" contentplaceholderid="MainContent">


       <h3>Log Items</h3>
       <asp:listview id="logListView" runat="server" itemplaceholderid="itemPlaceHolder" clientidmode="Static" enableviewstate="false">
           <layouttemplate>
               <ul id="logUl">
                   <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder"></li>
               </ul>
           </layouttemplate>
           <itemtemplate>
               <li><span class="logItem"><%#Container.DataItem.ToString() %></span></li>
           </itemtemplate>
       </asp:listview>

   </asp:content>
   ```
3. Edit the default.aspx.cs codebehind file to include the following event

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       var myLog = new List<string>();
       myLog.Add(string.Format("{0} - Logging Started", DateTime.UtcNow));

       logListView.DataSource = myLog;
       logListView.DataBind();

   }
   ```
4. Add SignalR packages via NuGet. (Trying searching for "Microsoft ASP.Net SignalR JS" and "Microsoft ASP.Net SignalR JS")
5. Create a Hub class

   ```
   public class LogHub : Hub
   {

       public static readonly System.Timers.Timer _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

       static LogHub()
       {
           _Timer.Interval = 2000;
           _Timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
           _Timer.Start();
       }

       static void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
       {
           var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("LogHub");
           hub.Clients.All.logMessage(string.Format("{0} - Still running", DateTime.UtcNow));
       }

   }
   ```
6. Setup the following script block at the bottom of your page (your jquery and jquery.signalr version may vary)

   ```
   <script src="Scripts/jquery.1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://www.codeproject.com/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

       $(function() {

           var logger = $.connection.logHub;

           logger.client.logMessage = function(msg) {

               $("#logUl").append("<li>" + msg + "</li>");

           };

           $.connection.hub.start();

       });

   </script>
   ```
7. Add the following to the Application_Start event handler in global.asax.cs

   ```
   void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
   }
   ```

Comment: Stephen thanks for the link.but it show error in Globel.asax, (Bundleconfig does not exist in current context,Authcnfig doesnot exist in current context)

Comment: I again facing an error System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection does not contain a defination for MapHubs

Comment: Did you install the SignalR package?

Comment: Yes sir, I Install the SignalR Compleate Package,can you tell me in which assembly file MapHub contains

Comment: edited the answer (no need for passing "~/signalr" to the MapHubs method

Comment: For Asp.net 4.8 "RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();" is obsolete and dont compile, you need to use OwinStartup startup class...

Answer (score 41):

The answer provided by @Stephen is now outdated as it does not apply to the latest Version of SignalR (v2.2.0). Also there are few other things that are not mentioned which IMHO might help future readers to **quickly** get started with SignalR using the Good old Webforms framework. The solution might appear tedious but it is not. I hope it helps people who visit this page looking to get help on SignalR for Webforms.

**Pre-Reqs:**
(Versions used by me are in brackets) . I have **NOT** tested this solution on other versions

1. MS Visual Studio 2015/2013. (2015) On Win-7 x64
2. .Net FrameWork version 4.5 or Higher (4.5.2)
3. SignalR version 2.2.0 from NuGet (Release Date 01/13/2015)
4. jQuery ver 1.6.4
5. Owin v1.0.0 and few others like Json, owin.Security etc... (see packages.config)
6. IIS v7.0 and above. Works on IIS Express version 10.0 that ships with VS2015.

**Steps**:

Follow the steps below to get SignalR working in a WebForms Project. The Aim of this project is to broadcast timestamps at periodic intervals to all connected clients (browser sessions) using SignalR. Only the first timestamp is generated by the Server Side code in the code behind file. Rest comes from the SignalR HubClass which is responsible for generating the Timestamps at periodic intervals and bradcast them to ALL connected sessions.

1. In Visual Studio (2015) Create a Empty WebForms Project.( Pick Empty Template  and check WebForms under "Add Core Librares and Folders). Lets say we name it as "SignalR_WebForms".
2. To Download, Install and add references to SignalR+jQuery+Owin libraries

   2a. Tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Manage Nuget Packages for Solutions.

   2b. Type "Microsoft.ASPNet.SignalR" in Search and pick "Microsoft.ASPNet.SignalR" (server component).

   2c. On the Right Panel  Now check the box next to "SignalR_WebForms". This will enable the "Install" button. Pick the latest Version (2.2.0 as of today) and click on the Install Button. This will popup a "Review Changes" dialog box which informs you of all the packages (total 10) that will be installed. Click Ok. Then Click on"Accept" to Accept the License Terms. This will start the download and install process (very quick). Once done open the Packages.config file (which is located under the root of the proj folder) and it should look like this :

`

```
<-- Packages.config should look like this  -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="jQuery" version="1.6.4" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

`

3. Add a webform and name it as default.aspx ( RightClick on Proj Add --> Webform --> type default.aspx --> click ok.
4. Copy paste this code into the default.aspx file (Markup)

`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SignalR_WebForms._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>SignalR Using webForms</title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {

            var logger = $.connection.logHub;

            logger.client.logMessage = function(msg) {

                $("#logUl").append("<li>" + msg + "</li>");

            };

            $.connection.hub.start();

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <h3>Log Items</h3>
    <asp:listview id="logListView" runat="server" itemplaceholderid="itemPlaceHolder" clientidmode="Static" enableviewstate="false">
        <layouttemplate>
            <ul id="logUl">
                <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder"></li>
            </ul>
        </layouttemplate>
        <itemtemplate>
                <li><span class="logItem"><%#Container.DataItem.ToString() %></span></li>
        </itemtemplate>
    </asp:listview>



    </div>



    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`

5. Copy paste the code below into the code-behind file (default.aspx.cs)

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SignalR_WebForms
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myLog = new List<string>();
            myLog.Add(string.Format("{0} - Logging Started", DateTime.UtcNow));

            logListView.DataSource = myLog;
            logListView.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

`
```

6. Add the App_Code folder to the project. ( Right Click on Proj --> Add --> Add ASP.Net Folder --> Pick App_Code ).
7. Add a SignalR Hub Class  and name it as LogHub.cs To do this Right click on App_Code Folder --> Add --> Pick Class .. (at the bottom of the list) --> Click on Vsual C# then Web then SignalR --> Pick SignalR HubClass  --> type LogHub.cs as filename. Click ok.
8. Open the LogHub.cs class file and delete existing code and Copy paste code below into it. Save.

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace SignalR_WebForms.App_Code
{
    public class LogHub : Hub
    {
        public static readonly System.Timers.Timer _Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        static LogHub()
        {
            _Timer.Interval = 5000;
            _Timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
            _Timer.Start();
        }

        static void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("LogHub");
            hub.Clients.All.logMessage(string.Format("{0} - Still running", DateTime.UtcNow));
        }
    }
}
```

`

9. Add a Owin Startup Class file and name it as Startup1.cs. ( Right Click on App_code --> Add --> Class --> Click on Vsual C# then Web then General --> Pick Owin Startup class.)  Delete existing code and Copy paste code below into this class file.Save.

   `

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using Microsoft.Owin;
   using Owin;

   [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication1.App_Code.Startup1))]

   namespace WebApplication1.App_Code
   {
       public class Startup1
       {
           public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
           {
               app.MapSignalR();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

`

10. Build and Run the Proj (F5). If no errors , you should see the following output on the local browser.

`

```
Log Items
•06/04/2016 09:50:02 PM - Logging Started
•06/04/2016 09:50:06 PM - Still running
•06/04/2016 09:50:11 PM - Still running
•06/04/2016 09:50:16 PM - Still running
•06/04/2016 09:50:21 PM - Still running
.....
.....
.....
.....
Keeps Going **without** having to refresh the Browser.
```

`

11. From a remote PC access the same site and you should get the exact same timestamps. This verifies that the site works as expected.
12. To further verify Right Click on the Browser and click View Source. On I.E this opens up a Notepad window with page html. Find "logUL" and you should see just the markup that shows the  initial timestamp. There is no markup that shows the remaining updates as those are injected by the SignalR hub. This is similar to AJAX.

`

```
<div>
<h3>Log Items</h3>
        <ul id="logUl">

            <li><span class="logItem">06/04/2016 09:50:02 PM - Logging Started</span></li>

        </ul>

</div>
```

`

Thats it !. HTH !!

Comment: Thanks for providing detailed answer +1 to you

Comment: hi, what is this code for <script src="signalr/hubs"></script> ? , in your instruction you're not mentioning to create signalr folder.

Comment: @GustiArya add nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb

Comment: What if none of the clients are browsers? To what url should I point the clients to get the messages?

Comment: @The Berga sorry I cant tell ... I have long since moved on to other tech stacks and I currently do not even have a PC with Visual Studio to check this :( . Gosh its been 4+ yrs already since I wrote this answer. Man does time fly or what !!  But just looking at my answer it would be whatever url you will use in step 11. To find that out you will need to build the project and run it in VS and it would open in a browser typically with a http://localhost:port/something/ kinda url ( if so ) replace localhost with the hostname of Visual Studio PC and that would be the remote url to point to.

Comment: Tested and works with the lasted asp.net 4.8 webforms and jquery 3.6.0

Comment: Make sure to use the correct jquery version, the installed version can be found in the Scripts folder     <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.3.js"></script>

Answer (score -3):

type this in Package Manager Console :

```
install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Version 1.1.3
```