# How to make two users interact in ASP.NET WebForms in real time

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, real-time

I'll need to develop a simple system (in it's essence):

We'll have a bunch of users, the users will have their demands. Each user will create a demand and will specify what user is responsible for the demand. When the demand sent is completed, the user that received the demand will notify this to the one who created it. Basically, it's it.

So, for a better understanding, lets pretend there are two users (A and B):

- A will create a demand for B;
- At the moment that A clicks the button to create the demand, B receives it right in his screen (without posting back the page or loading from DB in a time interval);
- Then, B will see A's demand, will work at it and, when finished, will notify A that the demand is completed.

Is there any way to do this **without MVC**? If so, what's the name of the plugin, method or any other technology that could be used?

Comment: Although your question is off-topic but you could have a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

Comment: I'd searched about and I've found SignalR, but it's just for MVC, isn't it?

Comment: Using standard callbacks, you could implement something similar to "push" logic. Have your page perform a callback to the server (no post back from the user's perspective), then the server basically holds that callback request until there's something to tell the user (they have a new demand, a demand they've sent has been satisfied, etc.), and then the server responds to the callback with a message. Client side, you receive the response, display the message to the user, and issue another callback to wait for the next message to be displayed.

Comment: No. It also works with ASP.NET Web Forms.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143599/can-signalr-be-used-with-asp-net-webforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used SignalR and it worked, as proposed by **S.Akbari**.

The question mentioned by **Nikki9696** was used too:

[Can SignalR be used with asp.net WebForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143599/can-signalr-be-used-with-asp-net-webforms)