# How to use SignalR real-time chart in ASP.Net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, signalr, amcharts4

I want to use SignalR in my project for real time chart updates.

My project is developed in WebForms with VB.Net Language.

I searched for for 3,4 days but all I found were MVC examples. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Please notice me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use SignalR with webforms, see this question for example : 
[Can SignalR be used with asp.net WebForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143599/can-signalr-be-used-with-asp-net-webforms)

However, it will require to make your current webforms project evolve in several ways, which can be a loss of time and a risk if it's an old project hard to maintain.

An alternative could be to create a completely new web project for the backend with everything required for a clean support of SignalR server, and to consume it in JS (using jquery.signalr, etc) from your currently existing webforms pages on client side.

The ability to achieve this kind of thing will depend of what version of .Net and SignalR you could/must support.

Comment: Yup, will take the risk. I have tried the example that you gave to me, my question now .. is it applicable to us SQL Select to trigger signalR or something like that.. that will refresh the chart or add data to chart? Thank you